# AdoptOpenJDK suggests that openjfx (javafx) has potential safety issues, is this correct?

Tags: security, javafx, adoptopenjdk

In the [FAQ section of AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/faq.html) near the bottom they suggest that due to the slow patching of JavaFX, it has (potential) safety issues. Is that a correct statement or is it still OK to make java apps with javafx GUI ?

I need to start up a new (long term commercial distributed) project and I'm not sure if javaFX is the one to pick due to this rather negative comment.

I know this question could trigger opinions, but that is not my intention. I like both JavaFX and Swing and I do not need help on being reminded that these tools are both great ! I'm concerned about the safety due to this article.

Comment: What is your target version? The comment you might refer is about OpenJFX 8. OpenJFX 11 has (commercial) [LTS](https://gluonhq.com/services/javafx-support/), it is actively maintained and there are new (free) [releases](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) every 6 months, like in OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks José. The target is OpenJFX 11. They mention 11 as being better, but they also end with (at the bottom) that if a credible interest group with the same release schedule would provide long term support, they might work together. This, at least, implies that something might not be right. The version 11 however seems to look looks OK for me.

Comment: With different words, the unpatched free JavaFX 11.0.2 version is not safe to be bundled with the OpenJDK new versions. They are asking for someone to do OpenJFX LTS for _free_, which won't happen. But you have a commercial LTS offering (releasing 11.0.10 in a few days and providing support), and you still have free JavaFX 15.0.1 and 16-ea+XX with all the patches as well. In any case, these offerings are not bundled with OpenJDK, but that is not an issue, you can download them from Maven Central.

Comment: @Geertie You can always use and bundle the latest version of JavaFX including all patches with your application even if, for some reason I don't understand, you are still bound to Java 11. So in practice there is no problem you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to José Pereda and mipa !

I have copied their answers and bundled them as the final answer to my question.

José Pereda:

> With different words, the unpatched free JavaFX 11.0.2 version is not
> safe to be bundled with the OpenJDK new versions. They are asking for
> someone to do OpenJFX LTS for free, which won't happen. But you have a
> commercial LTS offering (releasing 11.0.10 in a few days and providing
> support), and you still have free JavaFX 15.0.1 and 16-ea+XX with all
> the patches as well. In any case, these offerings are not bundled with
> OpenJDK, but that is not an issue, you can download them from Maven
> Central.

Mipa:

> You can always use and bundle the latest version of JavaFX including
> all patches with your application even if, for some reason I don't
> understand, you are still bound to Java 11. So in practice there is no
> problem you have to worry about.